# Open website after clicking notification

Tags: java, android

I want to open a website when a push notification is clicked on Android.

This is my code, and it opens the main Activity when I click the notification
. How can I open a website / URL in the browser instead ?

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("Big4Com").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg)).setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: if you want to load a webpage you can put a `webView` in your `MainActivity.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://your-website.com"));
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("Big4Com").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg)).setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```